# How to change layout of a UITableViewCell with a UIStackView

Tags: ios, swift, interface-builder

I have a custom UITableViewCell with a vertical UIStackView. The stack view in-turn has 2 UILabels, one of it is hidden by default. How to change the height of the cell to show both labels in the stack view properly when the second label is unhidden. On a button click when i show the second label, it tries to show both label with the same height overlapping each other, however when i scroll the view up and down, it re-renders it ok.

I tried to call SizeToFit and LayoutIfNeeded with no help. How do i change the height of the row/cell to show both labels in the stackview to look proper?

[image: Cell with a stackview and second label hidden]
[image: Cell with a stackview and second label unhidden]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the button click, the label 2nd is showed, you should reload the table view, or reload exactly the cell, the height of cell will change and the cell will be re-rendered

Answer (score 1):

You can call

```
tableView.beginUpdates()
tableVIew.endUpdates()
```

After tap on button, and your cell change height. It solution is compatible with animation.

Answer (score 0):

Try reloading that row with `reloadRows(at indexPaths: [IndexPath], with animation: UITableView.RowAnimation)` after you click the button that shows both labels.